# How to implement a typewriting effect within input() function?

Tags: python, input

I am attempting to write a small program that will detail a mission for a ttrpg campaign. The program will initially ask for a name using the input() function but I want the question to be displayed using a typewriter effect.

I have the typewriting effect already working on regular text being displayed.

```
# -----Typewriter Template-----
import time, sys, os                
from random import uniform

def typewriter(str):                

  for letter in str:                
    sys.stdout.write(letter)        
    sys.stdout.flush()              
    time.sleep(uniform(0, 0.2))
```

I want to use it like this:

```
code_name = input(typewriter("Enter preferred codename: "))
```

However, when implemented in this way I get the required effect but then it ends with 'None'. Like this:
'Enter preferred codename: None'

I'm still able to enter a name and the rest of the script executes as normal but why does it do that and is there a work around?

I checked around and couldn't find any other questions similar to mine, I'm not using pygame or ptinker or anything like that.

Comment: `input` expects a string as a prompt, but `typewriter` already produces the prompt so `input` doesn't have to. Just do `typewriter("Enter preferred codename: ")` first and then do `code_name = input()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typewritter function returns a None value which the input prints to the terminal. To fix this you can simply return an empty string instead.

```py
# -----Typewriter Template-----
import time, sys, os                
from random import uniform

def typewriter(str):                

  for letter in str:                
    sys.stdout.write(letter)        
    sys.stdout.flush()              
    time.sleep(uniform(0, 0.2))
  return ''

code_name = input(typewriter("Enter preferred codename: "))
```